# Syntax error 1064 - insert doesn't work as stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created an insert query that works as a sql statement, but when I try to implement it as a stored procedure through MYSQL Administrator I get MYSQL Error 1064 "You have an error in your SQL syntax. ...near DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE"
Here's the statement:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `LoadRecs_proc`;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `LoadRecs_proc`()
BEGIN

INSERT into Assignments_tbl (AccountId, ActivityID, ActivityDate, pname, CustomerName, GroupName, ProviderName, Contact, Phone, Extension, Selected, Closed)
Select
  tbl_ca.AccountId,
  tbl_ca.ActivityID,
  tbl_ca.ActivityDate,
  Concat_Ws(', ', tblcust.`Last Name`, tblcust.`First Name`) As pname,
  cust.CustomerName,
  tbl_cp.GroupName,
  tblproviders.ProviderName,
  tblproviders.Contact,
  tblproviders.Phone,
  tblproviders.Extension,
  0 As Selected,
  0 As Closed
From
  (((tbl_ca Inner Join
  (tbl_cp Inner Join
  cust.On tbl_cp.UID= cust.UID)
On tbl_ca.AccountId = tbl_cp.AccountId) Inner Join
  tblproviders On tbl_ca.ProviderId = tblproviders.ProviderId)
  Inner Join
  cust On tbl_cp.CustomerId = cust.CustomerId)
  Left Join
  FollowupAssignments_tbl On tbl_ca.ActivityDate =
    FollowupAssignments_tbl.ActivityDate And
tbl_ca.ActivityID =
FollowupAssignments_tbl.ActivityID And
tbl_ca.AccountId = FollowupAssignments_tbl.AccountId
Where
  tbl_ca.ActivityID = 76 And
  tbl_ca.ResponseDate Is Null And
  tbl_cp.Status = "Active" And
  tbl_cp.CustomerId = 33  And
  FollowupAssignments_tbl.AccountId Is Null And
  FollowupAssignments_tbl.ActivityID Is Null And
  FollowupAssignments_tbl.ActivityDate Is Null
  ;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap the first to lines.  You want to run the `DROP PROCEDURE` before setting the delimiter for your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

From this:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `LoadRecs_proc`;
```

To this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `LoadRecs_proc`;
DELIMITER //
```

Comment: Now it says "... near DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `LoadRecs_proc`()
BEGIN"
'at line 8

Comment: Line 8 is where the Delimiter keyword is located.

Comment: Exit your client and reenter.  Do the DROP, terminated by ";". Then do DELIMITER // -- on a line by itself.  And continue on with the CREATE.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the DROP PROCEDURE. I eliminated that and it runs. It wasn't the IF EXISTS either.
This is MYSQL 5.7.3-m13 64 bit community version.

Thanks for your help.